# [delphi]How can I detect whether a folder is in use or not?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I write two thread in one project.

Thread1 is used in coping all files and child folders in folder1 to folder2.

Both of folder1 and folder2, folder3 are from input.

Thread2 is used in checking whether folder2 has any file or child folder, if true ,Move them to folder3(Copy them to folder3, then remove them from folder2).

There has a problem.

Example1

folder1 'C:\Test\1'

folder1's children

C:\Test\1

C:\Test\1\L.tex

C:\Test\1\sdf.txt

C:\Test\1\2031   <--- it's folder

folder2 'D:\Sdf\555'

folder3 'D:\Sdf\492pS1'

**project running...**

Thread1 create D:\Sdf\555\1

Thread2 move D:\Sdf\555\1 to D:\Sdf\492pS1\1

Thread1 create D:\Sdf\555\1\2031(D:\Sdf\555\1 is removed)

**error...**

How can I detect whether a folder is in use or not?

Comment: Are you really copying and then removing? That's hugely wasteful. Use plain `move`. I'd use `SHFileOperation` to move a folder. If it fails, wait for a short time and try again.

Comment: What's your mean? Is there any api about moving dir I can use?

Comment: Yes there is. I already told you its name.

Comment: @user1531714 - if source and dest paths are on the same partition - then MOVE is RENAME :-)

Comment: @user1531714 did you ever opened Google? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239.aspx and ... lot of.

Comment: Dear  @Arioch 'The. Sorry, my program is used in delphi. :)

Comment: Delphi can also use the Windows-API here! No difference here, the Links are useful for you, please study them...

Comment: @user1531714 still u used SHFileOperation which is no less Windows-function than MoveFile*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx